# How to remove gradient effect appearing for IsMouseOver in WPF ListViewItem's style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the following `Window` I define a trigger for `IsMouseOver`. The background color is changed correctly, but it has an gradient effect. See the pic below. How to get rid of the effect? [image]

Only `Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Hover` is moved from separate style file to code excerpt below.

```
<Window x:Class="MyCompany.Application.Shared.UI.Dialogs.SomeWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="#FFF3F3F7">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.BorderBrush" Color="#FFF3F3F7" options:Freeze="True" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background" Color="White" options:Freeze="True" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Hover" Color="#FFAEAEB6" options:Freeze="True" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Active" Color="#FF0D6AA8" options:Freeze="True" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.HoverSelected" Color="#FF009AD9" options:Freeze="True" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Disabled" Color="#FFAEAEB6" options:Freeze="True" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme.DataGrid.Row.Foreground.Selected" Color="White" options:Freeze="True" />

        <Style x:Key="GridView.ColumnHeader.Gripper.Style" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" >
            <EventSetter Event="FrameworkElement.Loaded" Handler="GridViewColumnHeader_Loaded"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Thumb Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Gripper.Style}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" >
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.BorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Theme.TreeView.Background}"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Foreground}" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Cell.Padding}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Hover}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Active}" 
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Selected}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.Disabled}" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Background.HoverSelected}" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="IsGrouped"  IsChecked="{Binding IsGrouped}"/>
        <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">    
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mail"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Group"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Group}" />
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel (note that this uses our own ViewModel-class that i.e raises `PropertyChanged` events)

```
namespace MyCompany.Application.Shared.UI.Dialogs
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Mail { get; set; }

        public string Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        List<User> items = new List<User>();

        IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
        public ICollectionView Users { get; }

        private bool _isGrouped = false;
        public bool IsGrouped
        {
            get { return _isGrouped; }
            set
            {
                _isGrouped = value;
                if (value)
                {
                    Users.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Users.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        public SomeWindowViewModel()
        {
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com", Group = "OneGroup1" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com", Group = "OneGroup1" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com", Group = "TwoGroup2" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Pentti Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "pena.doe@gmail.com", Group = "TwoGroup2" });
            Users = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GetUsers());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ListViewItem` style you're using does NOT specify a `ControlTemplate`, and therefore, the _gradient effect_ you're seeing comes from the default one. So, if you want to get rid of that, you will have to define your own style/template. And if you play your cards right...:O), [you will get what you want](https://imgur.com/pIjFVy9).

Comment: thanks @jsanalytics!

Comment: You're very welcome !

Comment: BTW, please post your working solution !

Comment: BTW 2 : none of the answers in the supposed duplicate does it. If you apply the suggested style from the accepted, most up voted answer, [this is what you get](https://imgur.com/CB4zvSV). Notice that column data is gone.... so, major  **duplicate FAIL**... :O) I'm voting to **reopen** this question.

Comment: i'm getting back to this on weekend. i'll hopefully post the working solution (if reopened?). i checked the supposed duplicate maybe too hastily but i think i can manage without it.

Comment: Besides voting for reopen you can also  **flag** it for moderator attention. I actually did it, but it's been _pending_ .

Comment: @charm re-opened, please do share your solution

Comment: @Flexo: i really wish i had solution. as jsanalytics points out control template results in rows to be class names and not the data. there's now bounty  for this.

Comment: @charm can you please provide all the required brushes and a sample data source?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow: I edited and added hopefully everything needed

Comment: @charm not quite yet -- the brushes `Theme.TreeView.Background`, `Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Background`, `Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Foreground`, the colors `Color.Trimble_Blue` and `Color.Gray_4` are undefined as well as the `Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.FontWeight`. But I will try to find a solution regardless of the exact values of those.

Comment: sorry about that. i edit again.

Comment: Suggestion: create a `Duplicate Buster` badge...:O)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had some issues with the given code sample, e.g. missing resources or additional `options:Freeze="true"` which could not be resolved, therefore my solution may look a little different, but I think it does what you want: it removes the gradient effect.

---

The issue is that the default `ListViewItem` template has triggers which change the background (as you have found out as well) and the way around is to use a simplified `ControlTemplate` without any triggers.

This [example of a simplified template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42202301/7571171) works and you can put it in your `{x:Type ListViewItem}` to get a look like shown in the pictures below.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Using that template, this is what it will look like if you first selected `"Sammy Doe 7"` and then hover over `"Jane Doe 39"`,

[image]

and this is how it looks when you select (e.g. click on) `"Jane Doe 39"`:

[image]

---

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with

> as jsanalytics points out control template results in rows to be class names and not the data

but as far as I understand it, above code should not lead to that behavior. If it does, let me know and I will find another solution.

Comment: thanks! so this was a duplicate after all, but not duplicate of the one that is marked as duplicate of.

Comment: @charm kind of I think ;-) but it was tricky, because using a `ContentPresenter` instead of the `GridViewRowPresenter` lead to the binding error you described.

Comment: i tried already a week ago with GridViewRowPresenter  and all i got was class names. anyway i accept this and grant the bounty in the evening when i have time to try it a bit more (in case it breaks something else).

Comment: @charm thank you very much. I'm glad I could help, and if it does break anything, I will gladly try to help. I still have the test project I created for this, so it shouldn't be overly difficult.

Comment: Use this: `xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"`.

Comment: @jsanalytics thank you for mentioning the namespace, it looks interesting and I will look into it.

Comment: Also, you don't need to cave-in to a half-baked, "simplified" template. Soon you'll be where you started: without having full control of your stuff. In this case, triggers should be in the control template, not the style.

Comment: @jsanalytics I'm not sure I get your point. Sure, the template is not complete, but I meant "simplified" as in "without the triggers the OP does not need". Of course they can add all the triggers, properties etc. they want.